Paid resources in the resources post

Possible Duplicate:
Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese: should we include only free material? 

Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese
Can we add paid resources to this list? I'm no rich guy, or even upper class, but I find it a bit ridiculous that only free resources should be posted. Studying chinese is only free if your time is worthless...
I am interested in a speaking/listening course. I am looking through several options at the moment and wondering which one to go for.
On a related note, what is a more populated forum of English speakers learning Chinese?

Please post there. :)

By the way, commercial resources are now allowed. Check the dupe link.
